# Always empty metadata

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, media, qtmultimedia

I'm writing audio player using QtMutimedia, and need got audio file metadata.
I'm using this code, but always returns empty strings on every file. How fix this?

Qt 5.15.2 MinGw

```
QStringList meta = player->availableMetaData();
qDebug() << "File meta: ";

foreach(QString data, meta){
    qDebug() << data;
}
```

Comment: What is `player`?

Comment: `QMediaPlayer` object

Comment: Which OS? And more code is needed. Did you wait for mediaStatusChanged() after setting the media source?